# serve react create app and Nodejs app with reverse proxy Nginx

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, reverse-proxy

Trying to have both apps one react create the other Nodejs run behind Nginx proxy. The followings are my configs:

```
server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  site.com;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/site.com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/site.com.key;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;



    location /nodejs {
        root  /usr/share/nodejs;
        proxy_pass http://my.url.com:3009;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-for $remote_addr;
    }

    location / {
        root  /usr/share/react-create;
        proxy_pass http://my.url.com:3011;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-for $remote_addr;
    }
```

React app is being served at root but nodejs app files are not being served correctly:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

// Please try with this configuration.

```
upstream nodejs {
  server http://my.url.com:3009; 
}

upstream reactjs {
  server http://my.url.com:3007; 
} 

server {
listen       443 ssl;
server_name  site.com;
ssl_certificate     /etc/site.com.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/site.com.key;
ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

#charset koi8-r;
#access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

location /node {
    root  /usr/share/nodejs;
    proxy_pass http://nodejs/api;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-for $remote_addr;
}

location /react {
    root  /usr/share/react-create;
    proxy_pass http://reactjs;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-for $remote_addr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> First let Nginx handle serving your react static files form their build file, and reorder the location matching for Nginx and let the `nodejs` or the `api` server for later catch for Nginx:

```
server {
   listen       443 ssl;
   server_name  site.com;
   ssl_certificate     /etc/site.com.pem;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/site.com.key;
   ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
   ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

   root /path/to/project-base/build-live/;
   index  index.html;

   location / {
     try_files $uri /index.html =404;
   }

   location /api {
      proxy_pass http://myapistream;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```